# Automapper: inherited mapping does not include flattened properties

Tags: inheritance, automapper

I am mapping from an entity containing various value objects to a flat DTO using AutoMapper.

While I can map from the entity to the base DTO using flattening with `.IncludeMembers()`, when I try to add a mapping for the derived DTO using `.IncludeBase<Customer, CustomerDtoBase>`, it throws an error because it does not detect properties which are not explicitly mapped.

Here is some sample code which illustrates the problem. (Uncomment the bottom mappings to see the error):

```
// Entity
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set;}
    public Address Address { get; protected set; }
}

// Value object
public class Address
{
    public string Line1 { get; private set; }
    public string Postcode { get; private set; }
}

// Base Dto
public class CustomerDtoBase
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set;}
    public string AddressLine1 { get; protected set; }
    public string Postcode { get; protected set;}
}

// Derived DTO
public class CreateCustomerDto : CustomerDtoBase
{
    public string CreatedBy { get; protected set; }
}

// Derived DTO
public class UpdateCustomerDto : CustomerDtoBase
{
    public string UpdatedBy { get; protected set; }
}

public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static IMapper Configure()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<CustomProfile>();
        });

        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        return config.CreateMapper();
    }
}

internal class CustomProfile : Profile
{
    public CustomProfile()
    {       
        CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDtoBase>()
            .IncludeMembers(x => x.Address)
            .ForMember(m => m.Id, o => o.Ignore());

        // This uses default convention to map Postcode
        CreateMap<Address, CustomerDtoBase>(MemberList.None)
            .ForMember(m => m.AddressLine1, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.Line1));

/*  
        // This throws an error that Postcode has not been mapped
        CreateMap<Customer, CreateCustomerDto>()
            .IncludeBase<Customer, CustomerDtoBase>()
            .ForMember(m => m.CreatedBy, o => o.Ignore());

        // This throws an error that Postcode has not been mapped
        CreateMap<Customer, UpdateCustomerDto>()
            .IncludeBase<Customer, CustomerDtoBase>()
            .ForMember(m => m.UpdatedBy, o => o.Ignore());
*/          
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var mapper = AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();   
}
```

Is there something incorrect or missing with this mapping? Or is there a bug in AutoMapper/this feature is not supported?

I can work around this by explicitly adding all mappings for the nested object mappings, e.g. `.ForMember(m => m.Postcode, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.Postcode))` etc. But it defeats the point of using AutoMapper if you have to explicitly map each property.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/3162

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks for the response. If you've created a pull request for this feature, would you be ok to post the above as an answer? That way people will be able to see that this is not currently a supported feature, but will be added/fixed in version x.x, and I can mark this questions as answered. (You can't flag comments as answers.) Thanks.

Comment: Actually it was just merged. Try the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.